# Prove that $b^{\log_d(a)}=a^{\log_d(b)}$ and $\log_a(b)*\log_b(c)=\log_a(c)$

Tags: logarithms

How to prove $b^{\log_d(a)}=a^{\log_d(b)}$ and $\log_a(b)*\log_b(c)=\log_a(c)$

I've found this properties but the book doesn't include the proofs of them. Can you help me please?

Comment: For the first try taking logarithms to base $d$. For the second raise $a$ to the power of the two expressions on ether side of the equals sign.

Comment: Could you be more specific please? Thanks

Comment: @GniruT: Mark’s suggestion is very specific. Simply carry out the suggested operations and see what happens on each side.